# Module not found: Can't resolve '@react-icons/all-files' in gatsby sanity project

Tags: npm, gatsby, react-icons

I'm using sanity and gatsby for my project
after I installed react-icons with these command

```
npm install @react-icons/all-files --save
```

and import some icons to my project

`import { BiHomeSmile } from "@react-icons/all-files/bi/BiHomeSmile";`

and  run `npm run dev`  i'll get this error

> Module not found: Can't resolve  '@react-icons/all-files'

but it will gone when I'm using this

```
import { BiHomeSmile } from "../../node_modules/@react-icons/all-files/bi/BiHomeSmile";
```

i clean gatsby cach or run `npm install` it didn't work and I'm unable to remove node module folder if i delete it my project fail to build and run again i dont know why but it didnt worth to delete this folder and run npm install again

Answer (score 0):

first use `gatsby clean` to remove cache folder next uninstall react-icons module

```
npm uninstall @react-icons/all-files
```

install react-icons package throw root permission

```
sudo npm install @react-icons/all-files --save
```